# Are metals more reflective at lower temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, photons, reflection, molecules

I understand that when metal gets hot it loses its reflective properties, but does that also mean that the colder the metal is the more it reflects?

Answer (score 2):

All objects emit light in the form of black body radiation but when the temperature of the object is high enough the energy in the emitted radiation also increases. So when a mirror is heated up to the point it glows it is due to already emitted radiation now in the visible light spectrum.

So does a colder mirror means it reflects better? Im not sure but in the context of the answer I gave above it would not be due to the reason it glows when hot.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: It answers the first question of 'Why?' and predicts an answer for the second given the context. Seems better than no answer at all